# kernel 6.2.0-39 can't find nvme drive that 6.2.0-37 boots to

Tags: boot, kernel, nvme

(See edit a bottom of page)

Ubuntu 22.04 6.2.0-37 boots just fine
6.2.0-39 fails before the grub menu, message: nvme doesn't exist.

grub info from sata boot drive `grub.cfg`

```
menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-37-generic (on /dev/nvme0n1p3)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic--65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic root=UUID=65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic
}

menuentry "Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-39-generic (on /dev/nvme0n1p3)" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic--65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc' {
                insmod part_gpt
                insmod ext2
                search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc
                linux /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic root=UUID=65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
                initrd /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic
}
```

I don't know what is causing this
and I don't know where to look.

This is not a dual boot machine Linux only Ubuntu 22.04

Thanks Jim

Edit:  I gave you bad info the message when 6.2.0-39 fails is

No such device exists  65f1932f-e975-4d5f-a09a-74d0c1ef09dc

File /boot 6.2.0-39 not found.

Load kernel first.

/boot directory doesn't list any file for 6.2.0-39 how can I get them?

Currently running  Ubuntu 22.04 6.2.0-37

Comment: Try booting up into the `-37` kernel, then run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` then try rebooting into the `-39` kernel again.

Comment: You appear to be using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using an older & now *unsupported* HWE kernel, I'll suggest applying security fixes asap, as the 6.2 kernel came from 23.04 which is *fast* approaching its EOL, with 22.04 HWE already moved to the 6.5 kernel you make no mention of, ie. `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04      | 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7 | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x` is the current kernel which you don't even mention.

Comment: 6.5.0-14 won't work with my nvidia 390 driver so I am waiting for a updated driver or cash to buy a updated nvidia card

Comment: Rather than using an *unsupported* kernel, switching to the more stable GA kernel stack may have been a smarter move (ie. 5.15).  The default stack is set by your install media.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  Both stacks can co-exist except for when some closed-source kernel modules are used (this may impact you as some nvidia modules are the primary restriction) as both 6.2 kernels are missing security fixes.

Comment: These 3 should install the missing -39 kernel:  `sudo apt install linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic`.

Comment: guiverc   ls /boot shows a kernel vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic  but its not listed in the grub.cfg

Comment: following Terrance's advice I was able to boot into 6.2.0-39.  All looks good Thanks

Comment: You can use `sudo update-grub` to make your system re-scan for kernels available, but do note the file you mentioned is only **part** of what is required to boot a kernel; if you don't have full packages installed (*maybe you removed some of it*) they may not be detected.. My own system detects 6.6, 6.5 & 6.2 when I `update-grub`

Comment: guiverc  same here only 6.2 and 6.5 detected.